# Memorize inequalities about floor function

Tags: inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions, mnemonic

> Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Prove that:
> **1.**$\lfloor x \rfloor \le n \to x \lt n+1$
>
> **2.**$ \lfloor x \rfloor \lt n \to x \lt n$
>
> **3.**$  \lfloor x \rfloor \ge n \to x \ge n$
>
> **4.**$\lfloor x \rfloor \gt n \to x \ge n+1$

Since I'm not able to memorizing these inequalities , looking for a method based on reasoning in order to stick in mind .

Comment: Just draw a graph of $y=x$ and $y=\lfloor x \rfloor$.

Comment: They all come down to two basic properties: $\,x-1 \lt \lfloor x \rfloor \le x\,$, and $\,a \lt b \iff a+1 \le b\,$ if $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\,$. If you remember these, you can easily deduce the rest, rather than memorize countless variations.

Comment: Do you have an example for a method on reasoning? I am not really sure, what kind of answer you expect.

Comment: @Imago Yes , for example in order to find $\sin \pi / 2$ you can imagine graph of $\sin x$ and quickly answer instead of just memorizing some numbers .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[x]$ it's an integer number for which
$$[x]\leq x<[x]+1.$$

It's obvious if $f(x)=[x]$ then $f$ is a function and from here we can get all properties.

For example, if $[x]\leq n$ then since $[x]>x-1$, we obtain $x-1<n$ or $x<n+1$.

Comment: Thank you but how this helps me to memorizing them ?

Comment: @S.H.W I added a proof of the first property. Try to prove the rest by yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding .

Comment: @S.H.W You are welcome!